# jquery hide leaves whitespace in unbounce landing page

Tags: jquery

When adding custom javascript code in unbounce landing page, based on a yes or no question, the form fields and hidden and showed using jquery. The fields are hidden but there is a gap left within the form.

Comment: you are probably using visibility: hidden instead of display:none

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example? and is there padding or margin on the parent tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
use css display:block or display:none,  
$("#selector").css("display","block") // show
$("#selector").css("display","none")  // hide
```